# Toggle Mobile Data Based Upon Wi-Fi Network

Tags: wi-fi

I would very much appreciate assistance.

In my home ATT mobile network is just strong enough to keep my Samsung S7 from using Wi-Fi calling however there is not enough signal to have a conversation.

I wish to have Tasker turn Mobile Networks OFF when I am on my home network and then to have Tasker turn Mobile Networks ON when I leave my home network

Any help (the more detailed the better) anyone can would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you again for your time and assistance.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: No, my phone is stock

Comment: I don't think Tasker can do this without some add-ons, probably one to emulate "touch" by accessing the settings menu and toggling mobile data, a daunting approach for a novice with Tasker to use any plugin, much less one of the more complex ones that requires scripting. Probably better off to put a toggle on the desktop and just do it manually.